# Typesetting Chiasmus or structured, indented text

Tags: indentation, description

I need to typeset a [chiastic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure). Here is a simple example:

[image: ChiasmusExample]

The important parts are:

- Identification of the part of the structure, i.e., `A` or `A'`
- The text itself
- Consistent spacing between identification and the text
- Proper and nested indentation

This can be accomplished using `description` environments as shown below. Unfortunately, this breaks down for more complicated and longer structures. (For example, I can only nest `description` so many times.)

I've tried using the [verse](https://ctan.org/pkg/verse?lang=en) package, but it gets cumbersome very quickly and is prone to inconsistencies for anything but a small passage.

**Is there a better way to do this other than using many nested `description` environments?**

---

#### Example using `description` environment

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[A] No one can serve two masters
    \begin{description}
      \item[B] for either he will hate the one and
        \begin{description}
          \item[C] love the other; or else
          \item[C'] hold to the one, and
        \end{description}
      \item[B'] despise the other
    \end{description}
  \item[A'] You cannot serve God and mammon
\end{description}
\end{document}
```